# filtering objects with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to filter an object in angular controller. I always get undefined as a result in my variable and cant figure out why. I made a screenshot of my console. where you can see the object and the filter function. What am i doing wrong?

OK here is the main part of the function. Am getting back undefined, so it have to do something with the way am using the filter?:

```
this.update_lead_status = function (lead, sts) {

            this.status = $filter('filter')(leads.leads_status, { ls_id: 3 });

        };
```

[image]

The json object which is provided by a service:

```
leads.leads_status [
{ls_id: 1, ls_class: 'lost', ls_name: 'Status1'},
{ls_id: 2, ls_class: 'lost2', ls_name: 'Status2'}
]
```

I am trying to get back the object item based on the ls_id and asign the variables one by one to my scope! Thanks

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Here we go again with another one of your questions without enough detail for anyone to be able to troubleshoot the problem and problem itself is not even clear

Comment: what do you get from `$filter('filter')(leads.leads_status, {ls_id: '3'});` ?

Comment: i am getting back "undefined"...

Comment: We have no way to reproduce this without sample input data

Comment: @charliefl: What dont you understand? what else more can i provide?

Comment: the `leads.leads_status` JSON object value , the value of `sts`, and your expected result. Please.

Comment: I've made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cWVrV/424/) from your code, and it seems working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a [0] to the end of my filter function, like this:

```
var status = $filter('filter')(leads.leads_status, { ls_id: sts })[0];
```

Now it works fine for me!

Comment: Which meant the original didn't return undefined but an actual array like its meant to. Also there's no need for angular here, arrays have a native filter method that works the same.